# How to compile AI code accompanying "Artificial Intelligence for Games" by Millington?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to compile code ([link](https://github.com/idmillington/aicore)) accompanying "Artificial Intelligence for Games" by Millington in Windows.

Their readme suggests using scons to compile but it comes up with error:

```
scons *** No SConstruct file found.
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scons-2.5.1\SCons\Script\Main.py:, line 912, in_main
```

I even tried cmake gui but when I tried building the solution there is this error:

```
error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 1.
```

and

```
The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\user\Downloads\aicore-master\aicore-master\build\c03_pipeline.dir\Debug\c03_pipeline.tlog' because it is being used by another process.
```

They have already provided binaries but I want to compile it for learning purposes. It doesn't matter to me what way I compile it.

Comment: just from the error log it seems to be that the c03_pipeline.tlog is having a multiple acces error, have you tried implementing any sort of mutex? something like a bool indicating if the file is being accesed and to wait until it has been released

Comment: Thank for option but I haven't implemented mutex before. I was aiming to learn how to compile things from scratch but seems more challenging than I thought. I'll have to abort this and focus on smaller scale projects first then.